# Kiosk mode audio output problem

Tags: audio, systemd, kiosk, systemd-startup

When the Raspberry Pi 4/5 boots, I automatically start the Chromium browser (kiosk mode) with systemd according to the configuration below.

```
[Unit]
Description=kiosk app
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
User=pi
Group=pi
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=chromium-browser --kiosk http://192.168.1.220:9000


[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

A video plays on the screen. Even though bluetooth or AV Jack headphones are plugged in, the sound still comes out from HDMI. But when I run the same script manually, the sound comes out of the headphones, as expected. I want the sound to always come out of the headphones.

I tried the following:

- "hdmi_ignore_edid_audio=1" to disable HDMI audio output in /boot/config.txt
- "amixer cset numid=3 1" run any bash script to change audio output profile

But it didn't work.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you aware there is a tutorial [How to use a Raspberry Pi in kiosk mode](https://www.raspberrypi.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-raspberry-pi-in-kiosk-mode/) (possibly slightly dated because it suggests 32bit). Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I just tried it. Autostart is working properly. But there are some problems: 2 menubars appear at the top of the screen. Also, I get the connection sound from the Bluetooth headset twice(each boot) and but there is no sound. How can I fix this?

Comment: The whole point of a kiosk is it DOESN'T have a desktop (or any other user interaction). If you have a menubar you have done something wrong (possibly booting to desktop).

Comment: I understand what you mean, you're right. I was actually delaying Chrome's launch with the "sleep 10" command while trying to figure out the problem. Therefore, I have the chance to see the desktop. I format the micro sd and then try it by just adding this script. As a result, I still cannot get sound from the Bluetooth headset during startup. Then, when I run it manually again, it gets fixed.